# JS: How to extract nested string of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got an array with following data structure:

```
[
  { 
    _id: 'dgPMHw3ivRSp3wyWe',
    content: { 
      en: [{ content: 'foo', extended: 'bar' }, {...}],
      it: [{ content: 'any', extended: 'thing' }, {...}]
    },
    order: 1,
    parent: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ'
  },
  {...}
]
```

I need to modify this array to get only string values for `content` by selecting the first element of a specific language.

So for the english language the result should be:

```
[
  { 
    _id: 'dgPMHw3ivRSp3wyWe',
    content: 'foo',
    extended: bar,
    order: 1,
    parent: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ'
  }
]
```

I know I could get the string with

```
const language = 'en'
array.forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.content[language][0].content)
  console.log(doc.content[language][0].extended)
})
```

But how do I replace it to get my result?

Comment: Did you look at my answer....? Just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how without having to list each property:

```js
var array = [{
  _id: 'dgPMHw3ivRSp3wyWe',
  "content": {
    en: {
      content: 'foo',
      extended: 'bar'
    },
    it: {
      content: 'any',
      extended: 'thing'
    }
  },
  order: 1,
  parent: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ'
}];

const language = "en";
array = array.map(doc => {
  doc = Object.assign(doc, doc.content[language]);
  return doc;
});
console.log(array);
```

Comment: The language elements are array, so I used `doc.content[language][0]`

Comment: @user3142695 I don't know what else is in those arrays, but my code retains all the `en` information, regardless of its structure.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so:

```
  let result = data.map(e => ({
        ...e, 
        content: e.content[language].content,
        extended: e.content[language].extended
  }));
```

Comment: I do get a syntax error: Unexpected token for `...e`